Fixing a Python script automating job applications on Indeed
Both as a first "coding" project using Python and as a potentially useful tool; I'm looking to automate the job application process on Indeed.
I realise having the whole process of filling and uploading CV etc might be a bit too complicated- so for now I trying to get it to open each job posting in a new tab for me to fill out later.
This script is supposed to open the "apply now" (postuler maintenant in FR) in a new tab; it runs and opens safari. However, it quits after a while and doesn't interact with the page. There is a "accept cookies" pop-up showing up. Might that be the issue?
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from selenium import webdriver
import time

class IndeedSpider:
    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Safari()

    def apply_to_jobs(self):
        self.driver.get('https://emplois.be.indeed.com/jobs?q=job+étudiant&l=Bruxelles&from=searchOnHP&vjk=8038d2843bbd3e80')
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(10)  # Wait for the page to load

        apply_now_buttons = self.driver.find_elements("xpath", '//button[@aria-label="Postuler maintenant opens in a new tab"]')[:5]
        for button in apply_now_buttons:
            button.click()
            time.sleep(2)  # Wait for the page to load after clicking

# Instantiate the spider and apply to jobs
spider = IndeedSpider()
spider.apply_to_jobs()


